# Discourage Recommending Politics.SE for questions

Tags: discussion, questions, migration

I have noticed from time to time when a bad question gets asked on the main site that there is a suggestion to ask it on Politics.SE even though it would also be considered bad and closed on that site. Is there anything that can be done to discourage people from suggesting that questions get asked on Politics.SE and possibly other sites as well when they are deemed a bad fit on sketpics?

Here is the latest example

[What are the sourced counterarguments against including salary levels in the GHG Protocol?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/56594/what-are-the-sourced-counterarguments-against-including-salary-levels-in-the-ghg)

The question as asked on Politics.SE which is at 4 downvotes and 2 close votes at the time of this question.

[What are the sourced counterarguments against including salary levels in the GHG Protocol?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/84175/what-are-the-sourced-counterarguments-against-including-salary-levels-in-the-ghg)

Comment: I don't think anyone has found a solution to this problem across the network (it certainly isn't specific to skeptics/politics). I usually comment when I see someone recommend posting somewhere else inappropriately; I don't think much else can be done.

Comment: I understand but it seems like a bad experience especially for newer users to have a question closed, get recommended to ask it on another site, have that new question highly downvoted and closed on the new site. That doesn't leave a good impression on those users.

Comment: As the user who made that recommendation, I must confess that I was wrong to do so. I hadn't realised quite how opinionated and pushy the question was, but subsequent edits have made it all too clear. I certainly wouldn't have made that recommendation had the question been in its current state when I first saw it.

Answer (score 0):

From one mod's perspective:

First, I am going to answer a different question:

I very rarely migrate questions to other sites, for two reasons:

- When I started as mod, I was admonished not to migrate bad questions. It wasn't acceptable to throw our rubbish over the neighbour's fence. We should be very sure that the question would thrive in the destination site, perhaps checking with other mods first. So migrating meant knowing the rules of another site or several days negotiating.
- Migrating is useful when a question already has an answer. Migrating an unanswered question, generally <strike>with downvotes (because it is inappropriate) and</strike> a bunch of comments complaining it is inappropriate, means it starts its life on the new site with baggage. Better to just have the OP copy-and-paste.

If you add to that comments are second-class citizens and aren't carefully monitored, it means if someone comments "This would be better on this other site and should be migrated.", don't expect that to be enough to have a mod jump to action.

More relevantly, it means we are aware that suggestions to move a question to another site are often inappropriate.

---

This question is about whether comments suggesting a better site should be banned.

I would argue no because:

- Sometimes the suggestions are appropriate and useful.
- Whether it is appropriate is largely opinion-based (until it gets migrated or cross-posted and we see for ourselves).
- I would rather minimise how much mod powers are used based on our opinions. Inevitably, some decisions (e.g. was a comment abusive?) have require us to form an opinion, but the less subjective the rules are the better.
- Mods aren't monitoring every comments. It would have to be flag based.

I would suggest a comment countering the bad opinion with an explanation of why it is wrong.

Comment: I do tend to comment that the question should not be moved but they still tend to get asked on the other site and get heavily downvoted which is why I asked this.

Comment: "Migrating an unanswered question, generally with downvotes…and a bunch of comments complaining it is inappropriate" As a moderator, you should delete those comments before migrating. Also, the downvotes are cleared when the question is migrated, so the question really can get a fresh start. Of course, the other points about migrations still stand; don't migrate unless you are certain it will thrive on the other site.

Comment: @Laurel: The downvotes are removed? Huh. I thought the votes carried over. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, the same is true of the answers, which is unfortunate if the downvotes were for quality reasons. But a mod can (and should) delete any answer that's unsuitable before migration so it doesn't get moved over.

Comment: A couple of notes, this isn't about a question being migrated rather about a user posting the question again on politics.se. Also this isn't about banning users from suggesting migrations rather if there is a way to discourage the requests from being made unless the question is a good quality question to start with.